# UITableViewController AutoLayoutConstraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have drawn a border for the UITableViewCell

I have to set the leading and trailing constraints for the UITableViewCell, so that border will look correct.

To draw the border i have used the below code at `cellForRowAt(:)`

```
 let today = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "todo", for: indexPath) as! DisplayTODOTaskCell


                today.layer.masksToBounds = true
                today.layer.cornerRadius = 0
                today.layer.borderWidth = 1
                today.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
                let borderColor: UIColor = .black
                today.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
```

When I used the below code , I have got the runtime error.

```
today.constraints(NSLayoutConstraint(item: today, attribute: .alignAllLeading, relatedBy: nil, toItem: self, attribute: self, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLVqQ.jpg)

When I view from the phone  left and right border are not visible.

I have used TableViewController.

I could draw the border for the cell by leaving space .

Need I achieve for subsequent cell in different section ,for that **I need to know the height of the previous section**.Please let me know how to achieve this

I have added below code in the  UITableViewCell class.
      override func layoutSubviews() {
           self.frame = CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 5.0, width: 390.0, height: self.frame.size.height)
            print("1111 Height = (self.frame.size.height)")
            super.layoutSubviews()
        }

Comment: You need to show your code so we can help guide you.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of customising `Cell` directly, Create `UIView` inside `UITableViewCell`.

Add `UIView` inside `DisplayTODOTaskCell`by using `Storyboard`. Give constraints, {top 2, left 5, bottom 2, right 5}.

Inside this UIView, you can design whatever you need.

Give, `tableview` and `cell` `backgroundcolor` as `white`.

```
  let today = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "todo", for: indexPath) as! DisplayTODOTaskCell


            today.createdView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            today.createdView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
            today.createdView.layer.borderWidth = 1
            today.createdView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
            let borderColor: UIColor = .black
            today.createdView.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
```